# Continued fraction is hard to read

Tags: fractions

So this sort of ties into [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/121297/approximate-pi-out-of-small-numbers/) question on Puzzling.SE about making π out of the numbers [1...n] for n=[1,2,3...20]. I am currently working on a document using *L<sub>A</sub>T <sup>E</sup>X* that I am going to publish as an online reference when all n=[1,2,3...20] are figured out.

I am currently working off of my community wiki answer for the info and decided to jump to n=17 and input those formulas so I wouldn't have to do them later.

I currently have the problem with the continued fraction for n=20 being hard to read since it appears really small.

However, in case this is a problem that I would otherwise need to take care of, I am okay with the formulas being squished between the `\hline`s.

Picture of problem:

---

[image]

---

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
$n=$&Formula&Error&Credit\\\hline
1&1=1&2.14E0&Simd, 2012rcampion\\\hline
2&1+2=3&1.42E$-1$&Simd, 2012rcampion\\\hline
3&3=3&1.42E$-1$&Simd, 2012rcampion\\\hline
4&3+$\frac1{2\times4}=3.125$&1.66E$-2$&Simd, 2012rcampion\\\hline
5&3+$\frac1{2+5}=\frac{22}7$&1.26E$-3$&2012rcampion\\\hline
17&$\left(\frac1{10}\right)^{(4-6)/3}+8^{5-11}$&5.28E$-9$&CrSb0001\\&$-\frac7{12-2}-\frac{17-13}{14-9}$&&\\\hline
18&&&\\\hline
19&&&\\\hline
20&$3+\frac1{7+\frac{6-5}{15+\frac2{(10-8)+\frac{11-9}{(20\times14+12)+\frac{17-16}{13\times4}}}}}$&2.21E$-13$&Bubbler\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way I could make the continued fraction bigger so it's easier to read? I have tried using `\dfrac`, but it completely breaks the fraction.

Edit: This is what I mean by "completely breaks the fraction":

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Have you tried using `\cfrac`?  It's designed for continued fractions.  But I assume it does so by making the fraction bigger just as dfrac does, so "completely breaks the fraction may still happen".

Comment: @Teepeemm That just breaks the entire fraction just like `\dfrac`

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "breaking the entire fraction"?

Comment: but you did load amsmath?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Works, but now the fraction is pushing the columns off of the page. <strike>This is also happening when I remove the `c` in `\cfrac`</strike> Actually, then `\frac` just works like regularly

Comment: @CrSb0001 Never ignore error messages, by the way.

Comment: @Teepeemm I never got any error messages

Comment: if you tried \dfrac without amsmath you should have got an error. If you didn't see that change your compilation method or editor.

Comment: Re: "Works, but now the fraction is pushing the columns off of the page", isn't that to be expected? You wanted the fraction to be bigger, and that means less space on the page for the other columns.

Comment: @bonk Yes, but I wasn't expecting the other two columns to almost completely be pushed off the page

Comment: "Formulae" is the correct plural.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:**
Consider @Mico comment and change specification for third column type (1.2e3 --> 1.2e-2) and siunitx specification (added `print-zero-exponent` option to `sisetup`).

Like this?

[image]

For above table are used `tabularray` package with libraries `amsmath` and `siunitx` where the second column is defined to be in math mode and left aligned, the third column is `S` type as defined in `siunitx` and `tabularray` package.

Since table is quite wide, in table is used `\small` font size.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, siunitx}
\sisetup{print-zero-exponent,
         tight-spacing}
\usepackage{nccmath}   % for `\mfrac` (medium size fraction)

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {Q[c]
                        X[l, mode=math]
                        Q[l, si={table-format=1.2e-2}]
                        l},
            row{1}   = {guard, c, mode=text},
            row{2-Z} = {rowsep = 5pt},
               cells = {font=\small}
             }
$n$ & Formula   & Error     & Credit                \\ 
1   & 1=1       & 2.14E 0   & Simd, 2012rcampion    \\ 
2   & 1+2=3     & 1.42E-1   & Simd, 2012rcampion    \\
3   & 3=3       & 1.42e-1   & Simd, 2012rcampion    \\ 
4   & 3+\mfrac1{2\times4}=3.125
                & 1.66e-2   & Simd, 2012rcampion    \\ 
5   & 3+\mfrac1{2+5}=\mfrac{22}7
                & 1.26E-3   &   2012rcampion        \\
17  & \Bigl(\frac1{10}\Bigr)^{(4-6)/3}+8^{5-11} - \frac7{12-2} - \frac{17-13}{14-9}
                & 5.28E-9   & CrSb0001              \\
18  &           &           &                       \\ 
19  &           &           &                       \\ 
20  & 3+\cfrac1{7+\cfrac{6-5}{15+\cfrac2{(10-8)+\cfrac{11-9}{(20\times14+12)+\cfrac{17-16}{13\times4}}}}}
                & 2.21E-13  & Bubbler               \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you! This actually helped :)

Comment: A minor detail: Should it be `si={table-format=1.2e-2,print-zero-exponent}` rather than `si={table-format=1.2e3}`? I'll conced that the `print-zero-exponent` option would come across as quite pedantic.

Comment: @Mico, as usual you are right. I already edited my answer. Happy and prosper 2024!

Answer (score 5):

Just get rid of the `\hline` directives or replace them with `\addlinespace` directives. And, do get rid of all vertical rules.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,letterpaper]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage{array} % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for '\cfrac' macro
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\footnotesize % optional, for a 20% linear reduction in font size
\centering
$\begin{array}{@{} c >{\displaystyle}l L L @{}}
\toprule
n & \text{Formula} & Error & Credit\\
\midrule
1   & 1=1   & 2.14E0  & Simd, 2012rcampion\\ \addlinespace
2   & 1+2=3 & 1.42E-1 & Simd, 2012rcampion\\ \addlinespace
3   & 3=3   & 1.42E-1 & Simd, 2012rcampion\\ \addlinespace
4   & 3+\frac{1}{2\cdot4}=3.125 & 1.66E-2 & Simd, 2012rcampion\\ \addlinespace
5   & 3+\frac{1}{2+5}=\frac{22}{7} & 1.26E-3 & 2012rcampion\\ \addlinespace
\vdots \\ \addlinespace
17  & \Bigl(\frac{1}{10}\Bigr)^{(4-6)/3} 
      -\frac{7}{12-2}-\frac{17-13}{14-9} 
    & 5.28E-9 & CrSb0001\\ \addlinespace
18  &  \dots \\ \addlinespace
19  &  \dots \\ \addlinespace
20  & 3+\cfrac{1}{7+\cfrac{6-5}{15+\cfrac{2}{(10-8)+\cfrac{11-9}{(20\cdot14+12)+\cfrac{17-16}{13\cdot4}}}}} 
    & 2.21E-13 & Bubbler \\ \addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd opt for a more open look; also using `siunitx` for the third column seems the best.

If you set the font to `\small` and the continued fraction in `\footnotesize`, you're able to set the table in the standard text width. However, these adjustments depend on the text width you use.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
  output-exponent-marker=\mathrm{E},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\small
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-2pt}

\begin{tabular}{@{}ccS[table-format=1.2e-1]c@{}}
\toprule
$n$ & Formula & {Error} & Credit\\
\midrule
 1 & $1=1$ & 2.14E0 & Simd, 2012rcampion\\
\addlinespace
 2 & $1+2=3$ & 1.42E-1 & Simd, 2012rcampion\\
\addlinespace
 3 & $3=3$ & 1.42E-1 & Simd, 2012rcampion\\
\addlinespace
 4 & $3+\frac1{2\times4}=3.125$ & 1.66E-2 & Simd, 2012rcampion\\
\addlinespace
 5 & $3+\frac1{2+5}=\frac{22}7$ & 1.26E-3 & 2012rcampion\\
\addlinespace
17 & $\left(\frac1{10}\right)^{(4-6)/3}+8^{5-11}-\frac7{12-2}-\frac{17-13}{14-9}$ & 
  5.28E-9 & CrSb0001\\
\addlinespace
18 & & & \\
\addlinespace
19 & & & \\
\addlinespace
20 & 
  \footnotesize
  $3+\cfrac{1}{
    7+\cfrac{6-5}{
      15+\cfrac{2}{
        (10-8)+\cfrac{11-9}{
          (20\times14+12)+\cfrac{17-16}{
            13\times4
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }$ & 2.21E-13 & Bubbler\\
\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{The caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why `-2pt`? Because if I set the table without this adjustment, the overfull is a tad less than `12pt` and there are six intercolumn spaces to exploit.

Alternatively, you might do

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  c
  c
  S[table-format=1.2e-1]
  c
}
[identical body of the tabular]
\end{tabular*}

\caption{Table caption}

\end{table}
```

Comment: +1. Did you mean to write `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}` in the second solution? Adding `table-alignment=left` as an option for the `S` column type would help left-align the header word "Error". Incidentally, neither "18" nor "19" appear to occur anywhere in the continued fraction expression; this could be remedied [ouch!] by, say, replacing `2` with `2\times(19-18)`. :-)

Comment: @Mico Thanks for spotting the typo. Why are you suggesting left alignment? The header is perfectly centered in the column.

Comment: Ah, I was somehow thinking that the header cells should be left-aligned. Not needed.